# Cassandra compaction fails with "Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed"

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3 node Apache Cassandra 3.11.3 production cluster running since 2019, now suddenly it has started throwing error as below in system.log.

Quick help & resolution will be appreciated.

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:455628] 2022-10-14 05:50:14,602 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:455628,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.rawMean(EstimatedHistogram.java:231) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.mean(EstimatedHistogram.java:220) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.StatsMetadata.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(StatsMetadata.java:115) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(SSTableReader.java:1926) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.worthDroppingTombstones(AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:423) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getNextBackgroundSSTables(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.getNextBackgroundTask(SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java:183) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.getNextBackgroundTask(CompactionStrategyManager.java:153) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:268) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IllegalStateException` gets thrown when the compaction thread attempts to get the average ratio of droppable tombstones to cells for partitions in an SSTable. It runs into an illegal state when a partition contains more than two billion cells.

Another way of putting it is that you have a very large partition (maybe more than one) that has grown over time and has finally hit the limit.

This specific line from the stacktrace:

```
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.EstimatedHistogram.rawMean(EstimatedHistogram.java:231) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
```

shows that the exception is [thrown by the `EstimatedHistogram.rawMean()` method here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.3/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/EstimatedHistogram.java#L231):

```
if (buckets.get(lastBucket) > 0)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed");
```

Cassandra 3.11.3 is configured with 114 buckets which is capable of tracking a maximum of 2B cells ([from `MetadataCollector` class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.3/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/metadata/MetadataCollector.java#L47-L51)):

```
        return new EstimatedHistogram(114);
```

[CASSANDRA-15164](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15164) increased it to [188 buckets in C* 3.11.9](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.9/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/metadata/MetadataCollector.java#L52-L56) so it can now track up to 4B cells:

```
        return new EstimatedHistogram(118);
```

There is no workaround available for this issue. Apart from trying to keep your partitions smaller for performance reasons, the recommended solution is to upgrade to the latest C* 3.11 release (3.11.13 at the time of writing). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Erick Ramirez....For your quick help & explanation.